# Excel - Using a drop-down list to populate other drop-down lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete, data-validation

I have a sheet consisting of about 10 drop down lists (among other fields). I want to create a master drop-down list, which would populate some of the other drop-down lists and/or other fields based on the value chosen in the master list.

Would this be possible? Thanks!

**EDIT**
I appreciate all the answers! I think the solution from Werff may have answered my question, although I am having a little trouble getting it to work so I wanted to add more details to my question to make sure we are on the same page and also clarify with the other people answering.

[Picture of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEWvg.jpg)

In this example, Column A would be my master list. Columns B-D define dropdowns that would appear in other places on the sheet. If I select Steve from the master dropdown I would like the other dropdowns to all populate his preferences (for example Steve's House, Ground, and UPS). The same goes for the other people in the Shipping To field. Hopefully that makes the question more clear! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could use the excel LOOKUP function: Microsoft Excel LOOKUP is a Microsoft Excel function that searches for values in a column or row of a spreadsheet list or table. The V in VLOOKUP stands for vertical (column) while the H in HLOOKUP stands for horizontal (row).

Answer (score 1):

Put a list of *fruits* in column **C**, a list of *dogs* in column **D** and a list of *cats* in column **E**.  The DV dropdown in cell **A1** will allow the user to select either "fruit" or "dog" or "cat".

In cell **A2** we setup Data Validation with the List option and the formula:

```
=IF(A1="fruit",C1:C4,IF(A1="dog",D1:D4,E1:E4))
```

[image]

Now if you pick a category in **A1**, cell **A2** will show the items for that category !

From [My Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037057/show-dropdown-option-in-a-column-based-on-other-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, the idea is to select a value from a dropdown list, then have different values appear in other dropdowns based on the selection in the first one - is that correct?

If so, you can do this with Named Ranges.

Say we have our lists on Sheet2. You should have a master list or key list, the one that's going to control which of the other lists will be used. Each of the other lists should have a header that matches one of the entries on the master list. For the moment, I would suggest not using values that have spaces in them; there's a way to work around those, but it's more complicated.

Create named ranges for each of these lists. The easiest way to do it is by highlighting the whole range that contains all the lists and going to Formulas | Create from Selection. In the window that appears, "Create names from values in the:", check Top row and uncheck everything else, then click OK.

This has created a set of named ranges, one for each of our lists.  Now you can create your master dropdown. Go to the cell that should have the dropdown and use Data | Data Validation. Choose "Allow: List" from the dropdown. In the "Source" box that appears, type in the name of your master list. Hit OK.

Go to the cell that should have the next dropdown. Go to the same window, Data | Data Validation, choose Allow: List. This time, in the Source: box, you're going to put in a formula: `=Indirect($A$1)`, where $A$1 is the cell reference of your master list. Hit OK.

You should now find that when you make a selection from your master list, the options in the next dropdown are based on the named range that matches the entry you selected in the master list. You can repeat this as often as you need to make cascading dropdowns, though the naming can get messy after more than a couple of levels!

Answer (score 0):

I have used this solution many times, to retrieve part numbers, model, model names manufacture etc., just by using the drop down menu which has the required description of the product I want.

- Create your data validation list (preferably over to one side) and give it a name. I have called mine `data1`.
- Create your drop down list in cell `A1`
- In the adjacent cell type `=VLOOKUP(A1,data1,2,FALSE)`
- In the cell adjacent to that type `=VLOOKUP(A1,data1,3,FALSE)`
- In the cell adjacent to that type `=VLOOKUP(A1,data1,4,FALSE)`

You can use this formula as many times as you like for the number of columns and you can drag the cells down to copy into the next cell.